# how do i download from github instead of just copy pasting?

Tags: github, download

I go to a file with for example a .txt extension and there is no button to download, i have no option but to highlight and paste. This is ridiculous, how do i download such files from github? This system is so damn stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Click the **Raw** Link for the file, then (depending on your browser configuration) it will either prompt you to download the file, or it will just show the raw file in the browser and you can save it with `File -> Save As` or whatever the equivalent is in your browser.

Comment: that doesn't happen, when i go to the "raw" link, it just displays the source code.

Comment: In that case, you use the second option. I'm running Chrome on OSX, and I can save the file by using the browser's `File -> Save Page As` menu option.

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub Mate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-mate/baggcehellihkglakjnmnhpnjmkbmpkf) is the right tool to do, it's a Chrome extension currently. I felt painful as you, so I created this extension.
It's open source here https://github.com/camsong/chrome-github-mate.